# Incorrect Output from CSV File

Tags: java, csv

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Write a description of class ReadInCsv here.
 * 
 * @author (Kevin Knapp) 
 * @version (10-10-2013)
 */
public class ReadInCsv
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       String csvName = "Countries.csv";
       File csvFile = new File(csvName);
       ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> popList = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> areaList = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> gdpList = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> litRateList = new ArrayList<>();




         try
         {
           Scanner in = new Scanner(csvFile).useDelimiter(",");



            while (in.hasNext())
          {

           String name = in.next();
           nameList.add(name);
           String pop = in.next();
           popList.add(pop);
           String area = in.next();
           areaList.add(area);
           String gdp = in.next();
           gdpList.add(gdp);
           String litRate = in.next();
           litRateList.add(litRate);

         }
           in.close();
           System.out.println(nameList);
           System.out.println(popList);
           System.out.println(areaList);
           System.out.println(gdpList);
           System.out.println(litRateList);

         } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


    }
}
```

So im trying to read from a csv file and as it goes through it should add each scanned instance into a array list (im going to reference each element from these lists at a later point), but my outputs show that as soon as it reads something and adds it, it skips to the next line before reading the next string, i need it to read straight across, not diagonally

im sure im just missing something very simple, I just began learning java about a week ago, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big problem with this method is that unless each line in the file ends in a comma, newlines will not be delimited. A better way is to read each line in, split on commas, and add the values to the ArrayLists one line at a time:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(csvFile);
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] fields = in.nextLine().split(",");
    if (fields.length == 5) {
        nameList.add(fields[0]);
        popList.add(fields[1]);
        areaList.add(fields[2]);
        gdpList.add(fields[3]);
        litRateList.add(fields[4]);
    } else {
        // Bad line...do what you want to show error here
    }
}
```

An even better way is to use a Java library dedicated to reading CSV files. A quick Google search should turn up some good ones.

Comment: ah, i had something similar to this at 1st, i read everything into a long array but i started changing things for some reason, i prob shoulda just stayed on the idea path i started with

so lemme see if i grasp this, id prefer understanding, then just simply getting someone to answer the issue for me

i think i originally had one long array, so I assume using in.nextLine().split(","); will start with fresh iterations of element indexes (0-4), instead of continuing with index 5+ (which is what my original issue was

Comment: Yup your understanding of `in.nextLine().split(",")` seems correct. Another way to think about it is, a CSV file is pretty much a spreadsheet (Excel, etc.). Each row is a separate entry. You want to read in each row one at a time and then operate on that row before moving onto the next one, not chain the rows together or try to operate on each individual cell. If that makes sense.

Comment: ah yeah im using a excel sheet as a test csv for debugging my code

thanks alot, works perfectly now